# Binding Tooltip to a property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Why wouldn't the following style work?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=_FailCount, StringFormat='{}Fail Count = {0}'}" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: It doesn't show any tooltip. Though it does when I replace `Value` part above with a constant string.

Comment: any binding error in output window?

Comment: You should check the `DataContext`. If `_FailCount` is defined in the Binding for the column, it will work?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '_FailCount' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=17940505)'. BindingExpression:Path=_FailCount; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=17940505); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object')

Comment: I know for sure that the underlying DataTable contains _FailCount column.

Comment: In `Binding` must be a property of your `DataContext`, not a Column.

Comment: Can't see what's happening. Using snoop I see that the `DataContext` of my `DataGridRow` is `DataRowView`, which presumably is pointing to a row of the underlying `DataTable`, right?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The error was on my part. A piece of code was removing my column from the DataTable at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your binding this way :

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=[_FailCount], StringFormat='{}Fail Count = {0}'}" />
```

That should work given the DataContext is a `DataRowView`, because that's the way we access a column value from `DataRowView` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a cell, you can try ColumnHeader ,

```
  Style TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="ToolTip"  Value="{Binding Path=_FailCount, StringFormat='{}Fail Count = {0}'}", RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I don't want to apply it on the entire row, just that particular cell.

Comment: i modified the answer